# Gtk# c# Treeview how to preselect a row and header of column before window.ShowAll()

Tags: c#, treeview, gtk#

I've started using c# and gtk# under visualstudiocode(linux) by writing a todolist app.

on app start, no row is selected nor a column (out of4) and I'd like to have the first row selected and the header of 2nd column selected (this indicates that sorting is on 2nd column)

```
public class ToDoWindow : Window
{
        public static ListStore toDoList;

        public ToDoWindow() : this(new Builder("ToDoWindow.glade")) { }

        public ToDoWindow(Builder builder) : base(builder.GetRawOwnedObject("toDoWindow"))
        {
            SetDefaultSize(350, 310);
            builder.Autoconnect(this);
            DeleteEvent += delegate { Application.Quit(); };
            menuQuitter.Clicked += OnQuitterClicked;        // 1 item of menu
            toDoList = CreateListWindow();                  //creates Model of treeView
            treeView.Model=toDoList;
            AddColumns(treeView);                           // adds 4 columns 
            treeView.RowActivated += OnRowActivated;        //2nd column.SortColumnId = 4;
            toDoList.GetIterFirst(out iter);
        }
        private void OnRowActivated(object sender, RowActivatedArgs args)
        {
            treeView = (TreeView)sender;
            toDoList.GetIter(out iter, args.Path);
        }
}
```

I've been through all the post and tried every solution
I've tried `GetIterFirs` (like shown) : got the right values but no visual indication of selection.
I've no idea about 2nd column header selection for sorting

I would appreciate a start of a solution.